# How to save multiple variables in a apipeline for another job

Tags: variables, gitlab, gitlab-ci

So I am looking through the gitlab ci documentation for passing variables to other jobs. However, how would I pass more than one? And how would I access more than one?

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "BUILD_VERSION=hello" >> build.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "$BUILD_VERSION"  # Output is: 'hello'
  dependencies:
    - build
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can save several values in an artifact and than source it in a following job:

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "BUILD_VERSION=hello" >> build.env
    - echo "ANOTHER_VARIABLE=world" >> build.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - source build.env
    - echo "$BUILD_VERSION"  # Output is: 'hello'
    - echo "$ANOTHER_VARIABLE"  # Outpur is 'world'
  dependencies:
    - build
```

If you need to export the variables in the environment, just replace the `source` command by the following one:

```
  script:
    - export $(cat build.env | xargs)
```

Comment: From gitlab 13.0 no need to add `source build.env` since it auto passed in later stages.

You can refer more at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#pass-an-environment-variable-to-another-job